# JSONP working with Leaflet time slider

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, timeslider

I would like to integrate the time slider into a JSONP geoserver. Here is the current code I have http://jsfiddle.net/qcwcrwge/26/ and I would like to use the time slider with a layer called `feature.properties.time`.

I have tried to add the time slide libraries and the lines

```
var testlayer = L.geoJson(json),
        sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
            position: "topright",
            layer: feature.properties.time
        });

//For a Range-Slider use the range property:
sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
    position: "topright",
    layer: feature.properties.time,
    range: true
});

//Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)
myMap.addControl(sliderControl);
//And initialize the slider
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

Just after the line

```
}).addTo(coolPlaces);
```

But it does not work.

Do you know what the problem can be?

Answer (score 1):

For initializing the slider control, you will need jQuery and jQuery UI, too. Also, you have to include the `leaflet.SliderControl.min.js`, as you mentioned in your question.

To initialize the slider, you have to make a GeoJSON layer to pass:

```
var testlayer = L.geoJson(WFSLayer);
```

The slider control must be constructed with the GeoJSON layer, in this case called `testlayer`:

```
sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
    position: "topright",
    layer: testlayer,
    range: true
});
```

The last step is to activate the control, that is almost correct in your code snippet. You have to refer to your current map object, instead of `myMap`:

```
//Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)
map.addControl(sliderControl);
//And initialize the slider
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

Note: make sure, your GeoJSON features have a `time` property, like in the [demo](https://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/). You can have a glance at the demo features [here](https://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/points.json). I don't know if the plugin can handle time formats which differ from the example GeoJSON `time` property, it's up to you to test (or look it up in the source code).

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/qcwcrwge/30/.

Try to test your application in localhost, because as far as I can see, JSFiddle doesn't support range inputs.